# Is there any reference from the Church Fathers regarding the approximate time when the disciples asked Jesus in Matthew 26:17?

Tags: matthew, passover

Matthew 26:17 NIV

> **On the first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread**, the disciples came to Jesus and asked, “Where do you want us to make preparations for you to eat the Passover?”

I ask because I'd like to know if (according to the Hebrew calendar) the disciples' question and the eating of the Last Supper happened on the same day or on a different day.

A. Example of "happened on the same day":
If the timing when the disciples came to Jesus and asked, 'Where do you want us to make preparations for you to eat the Passover?' was not long after the first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread began, then my conclusion is that the Last Supper happened on the same day, the first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread.

B. Example of "happened on a different day":
If the timing when the disciples came to Jesus and asked, 'Where do you want us to make preparations for you to eat the Passover?' is in the afternoon (let's say, around 3 pm) of the first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread (so in a few hours more, the first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread ended), then my conclusion is that the Last Supper happened on the next day, the second day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread.

---

Commentary about **the first day of the feast** in Matthew 26:17

Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges

> the first day of the feast of unleavened bread. **This was the 14th of Nisan**, which commenced after sunset on the 13th.

Pulpit Commentary

> The first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread; literally, on the first day of Unleavened Bread. We have arrived at the Thursday in the Holy Week, **Nisan 13**.

Old Testament verse:

Leviticus 23:6

> And on **the fifteenth day** of the same month is the feast of unleavened bread unto the LORD: seven days ye must eat unleavened bread.

There are three different options about when is the first day of The Feast of Unleavened Bread: Nisan 13, Nisan 14, and Nisan 15.

How do we reconcile those three discrepancies? Or, why do the two commentaries not put the first day of the feast in Matthew 26:17 according to the Old Testament verse which is Nisan 15?

---

Based on the [Catena Bible](https://catenabible.com/mt/26), I quote the commentary from John Chrysostom for Matthew 26:17:

> By “the first day of the feast of unleavened bread,” he means the day before that feast. For it is customary always to reckon the day from the evening. He mentions this with regard to the evening of the Passover. **It was on the fifth day of the week they came to him**. As to **the time**, Mark says, “On the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread, **when they sacrificed the Passover lamb**.”

[Wikipedia: Passover sacrifice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_sacrifice#:%7E:text=The%20animal%20was%20slain%20on,of%20the%20Temple%20at%20Jerusalem.)

> **The animal was slain** on the eve of the Passover, on the afternoon of the 14th of Nisan, after the Tamid sacrifice had been slaughtered, i.e., **at three o'clock, or**, in case the eve of the Passover fell on Friday, **at two**

Me: (so it's something like my point B above)
**On the fifth day of the week around 3 p.m.** the disciples came to Jesus and asked, 'Where do you want us to make preparations for you to eat the Passover?'

Me:
Then the Last Supper happen on the sixth day of the week?

---

From the same link, I quote the Cornelius De Lapide commentary :

> On the Friday, which was the8th day of Nisan, He came from Ephrem to
> Bethany. The next day, being the Sabbath, He sups in the house of
> Simon the leper. The day following was the10th of Nisan, and Palm
> Sunday. On the11th of Nisan, He taught in the Temple, and cursed the
> barren fig-tree. On the12th, He foretold the destruction of Jerusalem,
> and spake the parables recorded in S. Matthew xxiv. and xxv. On
> the13th of Nisan, or Wednesday, the rulers held their council, when
> Judas sold Him to them. On the14th of Nisan, He instituted the
> Eucharist. On the15th, He was crucified. The16th of Nisan was
> Saturday, when He lay in the tomb. The17th of Nisan was Easter Sunday.
> On the first day of unleavened bread, that Isaiah , the14th day of
> Nisan, or the full moon, Christ about mid-day sent two of His
> disciples from Bethany to Jerusalem to prepare and roast the paschal
> lamb, that He might eat it with them in the evening.

I made a chart based on the quote above something like this :
[image]

My own conclusion based on this commentary :
The Last Supper happen on the fifth day of the week. **After more than 24 hours**, Jesus died at around 3pm on the sixth day of the week. (???)

Comment: This question has been debated for centuries and never resolved.  It has a huge literature but almost nothing in the ante-Nicaean fathers.

Comment: We are not told so we do not know.

Comment: @Dottard, thanks for your comment. I've read some articles in the internet, but the articles mentioned only about the date, without including the timing. I'm intrigued to know the timing. For example, if based on the Leviticus 23:6 so that the first day of the feast in Matthew 26:17 is Nisan15 and the timing of the question being asked to Jesus happened at around 3 pm, it leads me to conclude that the Last Supper happen on Nisan16, the second day of the feast of unleavened bread.

Comment: https://catenabible.com/mt/26 see for early christians writings. The both commentaries u stated believe the date for it is 14. Pulpit is saying the day is 13, which will change soon at evening as 14, and the Cambridge simply states the 14th to be for the feast. The difference of the eating the Passover could be simply a minor calendar difference among Jews, acc to scholars. They may have disagreed with Pharisees. See related ques.

Comment: @Michael16, thank you for the link. If you have time, please read my edited question which is after I read John Chrysostom commentary from your link.

Comment: You answered your question. This has been explained by some scholars like reasonablefaith org. There was a calender difference, they ate it one day before the others.